# alias multi commands as one alias

Tags: command-line, alias

I made an alias for youtube-dl  with some options  like that

`yd="youtube-dl -cit -f 18"`

so I can download it like

`yd URL`

I want to modify it to show only the two lines from the output using

`grep -e "Downloading video #" -e ETA`

I can make it in two aliases using the `|`

but is there a way to make it one alias

Comment: unclear for me. Explain a bit more.

Comment: need instead of making 2 aliases and use them like ( alias1 URL | alais2  )  need to make it only one alias like alias1 URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to [make a function since an alias does not support providing parameters directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/shell-script-how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-unix-alias).

Open your `~/.bashrc` file and enter the following:

```
function yd() {
    youtube-dl -cit -f 18 $1 | grep -e "Downloading video #" -e ETA
}
```

and then source your `~/.bashrc` file using:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

and then you should be able to use `yd URL` to get the desired result.

Comment: @Jobin  yes it works this time , thanks for the help